# Android: Unable to resume Activity, java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-listview, onresume, resume

I have an activity that has a ListView implemented using a SimpleCursorAdapter. The ListView lists items from an SQLite Database. The problem is the it the I am reaching this activity on the press of a button from MainActivity. If there are no elements in the Database at this point the application crashes showing the error "Unable to resume Activity". If however there is at least one element in the database this activity works fine.I want to know how to get around this problem.

Here's the complete Activity Code. Please Help.

NOTE: I had done the exact same thing in one of my other applications except the alternate coloring of rows you see here and that worked fine.

```
package com.tintin.scheduler_3;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List_Course extends ListActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_list);

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(List_Course.this, Add_Course.class));
        }
    });
    Log.v("Button", "On Click Done");
    db = new DatabaseHelper(List_Course.this);
    Log.v("Button", "On Click Done2");
    displayList();
    Log.v("Button", "On Click Done3");
    db.close();
}

public void onResume(){
    Cursor newCursor = db.getAllCourses();

    dataAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
    super.onResume();
    db.close();
}

public void displayList(){
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllCourses();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0)return;
    String from [] = new String[] {db.colName,db.colDisplay};
    int to[] = new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor, from, to, 0){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if(position % 2 == 0)   
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
            else
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0D0D0"));

            return row;
        }
    };
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

}
```

Comment: why are you closing the db during the onResume()? Btw what does db.getAllCourses() return?

Answer (score 0):

In your onresume mtd  `super.onResume();` call must be **first** as

```
Cursor newCursor = db.getAllCourses();
dataAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

may takes **more time** to execute so make **super.onresume()** call first and then the cursor code.hope this helps.